# What if the earth stops orbiting the sun?

Tags: space, earth

Imagine that suddenly the earth permanently stops in its orbit around the sun. What happens next? Would it cause any hazards or catastrophes? What are the outcomes?

Comment: Does the earth staxy close to the sun as in eternal equidistance to the sun or is it ejected out of orbit?

Comment: @Tauchsieder the first scenario of your comment

Comment: @AkshayVasu Your question seems very broad, too broad to be answered concisely, I suggest you split your question into specific questions that can be answered more objectively to ensure high quality answers.

Comment: Does it also stops spinning?

Comment: Well, if the laws of physics still apply we will spiral in towards the sun. Smell ya later humanity.

Comment: @ScottDowney on the contrary, the consequences of losing orbit are well known and fairly few (they're just very serious) - this may not be the best quality question but I don't think it's too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, how would it stop? How much of it would "stop"?

Let's assume everything from the crust surface down just got an incredible pulse from a gravitational weapon making it stop moving along the orbit instantly.

Earth's orbital speed is 107,000 km/h, and the stop would mean deceleration from that speed to zero. Falling human's terminal velocity in atmosphere is 200km/h, and you can roughly imagine what happens to a human going splat by falling out of the plane. Now multiply that by 50,000 and apply to everything that isn't stopped.

Stuff on the side of Earth where it's between midnight and noon gets splattered against the surface exploding ; things on the evening side get launched into space, exploding into plasma blasts just scarce hundreds of meters into the atmosphere (from air friction). End of all life on Earth; the "evening side" bathed in gamma radiation from the plasma. Morning hemisphere is smashed with enormous craters by anything not firmly anchored or presently in flight.

The Moon, unless it was directly over "morning terminator" gets launched along Earth orbit; it's orbital speed is just a tiny fraction of Earth's orbital speed, and well below Earth escape velocity - it enters an elliptical orbit roughly similar to Earth orbit around the Sun.

Then, gradually, in a straight line, Earth begins falling towards the Sun. The acceleration is initially pretty low; merely 0.0058 m/s^2, compared to Earth gravitational acceleration of 9.8m/s^2.

Following the formula for [freefall in gravitational field of a large body](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/19388/radial-fall-in-a-newtonian-gravitational-field) we obtain nearly [43 days](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%282%20G%20%28%28Earth%20mass%29%2B%28Sun%20mass%29%29%29%5E%28-0.5%29%29%20*%20%28%20sqrt%28%28Sun%20radius%29*%281%20AU%29*%28%281%20AU%29-%28Sun%20Radius%29%29%29%20%2B%20%28%281%20AU%29%5E%283%2F2%29%29*%201%2Fcos%28sqrt%28%28Sun%20radius%29%2F%281%20AU%29%29%29%20%29) until Earth falls into the Sun, causing a relatively minor solar flare. In case any bacteria survived somewhere in deepest mines or under-ocean caverns, they will be scorched to ash within seconds.

Oh. There will be something left.

The oceans on the "evening side" may be deep enough to withstand getting hurled across the atmosphere without boiling away. They will form a ring of ice asteroids on the former Earth orbit. Maybe even some bacteria will remain in endospore form. If a visiting comet picks up some of the ice and carries it across space to other solar systems, where a planet similar to Earth in its early days (aminacid soup) exists, they may even be revived and regrow into Earth-like life...

Answer (score 1):

**Problem #1:** Sudden stop would compress one side and fling off everything not good enough attached into orbit. This will kill most life on earth, destroy cities, woods, fields and change mountains. Also this will create high and low pressure areas inside earths core, leading to earthquakes and a change in the rythm of volcanic activity. Lets assume either earth brakes at a reasonable speed or there is an inertia dampening field.

**Problem #2:** The earth going around the sun is the reason we dont drop into it and burn. Without an orbit we would need a force counteracting gravity

Now we have earth equidistant from the sun, and everything is fine, what are the consequences, besides our definiton of a year needing a little rework.
First, we would loose seasons as we know them, as the axial tilt would now be constant in its direction. This means, longer days on one hemisphere of the world than others. How specific areas are affected depends on when this event happens. But obviously this would drastically change the clima, making one side colder and the other hotter over time, causing mass evacuation and many species in both flora and fauna to go extinct. Some will survive even under those conditions or repopulate the barren areas from the central regions. The least changes would happen in the equatorial region, obviously drawing people in this region, increasing infrastructure and economy on the African continent.

Another aspect: distance from the sun. The distance from the sun varies throughout the year with an average of 149.5 million kilometer and a variation of +- 2.5 million kilometer. This means the date on which it will happen will decide if the average temperature of earth rises or falls. Unfortunately i cant calculate the results at the moment

Now about choosing the **date:** The further away you are from the 4th of July in any direction, the hotter earth will get. The closer you get to either the solstices, the more extreme the difference between hot and cold will get.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the Earth stops rotating on its axis but maintaining its orbit, like a car suddenly braking while driving on a highway, then one can imagine everything on Earth suddenly feeling its deceleration at 1,000mph which is its current speed. There would be earthquakes, floods, buildings falling over and general mayhem.

If the Earth's rotation slows down gradually, maybe imperceptibly, then the days would get longer and cause extreme weather conditions - hotter days and colder nights would lead to winters and droughts. When it stopped altogether a day would be as long as a year because each face of the Earth would take that long to see a different side of the Sun.